# Value does not retain in span while using jquery with ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a form as under

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="JQuery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
                $.ajax(
            {
                url: "Default2.aspx",
                data: "get=" + document.getElementById("TextBox1").value,
                success: function(data) {
                $('#lblServerResponse').html(data);
                },
                error: function() { alert(arguments[2]); }
            });

            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Enter your name:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Click Me" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                Server Response:
            </td>
            <td>           
                <span id="lblServerResponse"/>
            </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

After I enter some value in the textbox and click on the button, I am able to get the data but it is not retaining in the span.

What is the problem and how can I overcome this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need the controls be run server-side?

Comment: I have changed the server label control to span  <span id="lblServerResponse"/> but with same result

Comment: Have you tried my answer below? That is, changing all from server controls to client ones? If you have reasons to stick with server controls then it's fine, my answer does not apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can, use client-side elements instead:

```
<form id="form1">
<div>
    <input type="button" id="Button1" value="Button" />
    <input type="text" id="TextBox1" />
    <span id="Blah"></span>
    <!-- the hidden input may no longer be required -->
    <input type="hidden" id="Label1" />
</div>
</form>
```

Then your javascript will be like:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#Button1").click(function() {
          $.ajax(
          {
            url: "Default2.aspx",
            data: "get=" + $("#TextBox1").val(),
            success: function(data) {
                $('#Blah').html(data);
                $('#Label1').html(data); //the hidden input may no longer be required
            },
            error: function() { /* handle here */ }
          });
        });
    });
```